# Forcing Tikz to show only certain part of diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use the following code

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \draw(0,0)  +(90:1) arc(90:100:1)       arc(15:195:0.05);
    \draw(0,0)  +(90:1) arc(175:-5:0.05)        arc(85:77:1)    arc(160:343:0.05);

    \draw(0,0)  +(71:1) arc(71:65:1)    arc(155:90:0.085)   --(0.5,1.3);
    \draw(0,0) +(106:1) arc(106:115:1)  arc(25:90:0.085)    --(-0.5,1.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

to get something that looks like the following

---

[image]

---

But as you can see, there is a lot of extra white-space included because I am using (0,0) as an anchor to get at the relevant points and make everything line up correctly.

> **Question:** Is there some way that I can just get Tikz to show the relevant part and keep the code as it is, i.e. get rid of the unnecessary white-space?

Comment: Use `\clip[draw] (-.75,.5) rectangle (1,1.5);` and adjust the coordinates of the left bottom and right top corners of the rectangle. Then remove `[draw]` to simply clip the area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the bounding box:

```
 \path[draw,use as bounding box] (-.55,0.85) rectangle (0.55,1.35);
```

Remove `draw` option after you get the coordinates right.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
Some text here above the picture

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \path[use as bounding box] (-.55,0.85) rectangle (0.55,1.35);
    \draw(0,0)  +(90:1) arc(90:100:1)       arc(15:195:0.05);
    \draw(0,0)  +(90:1) arc(175:-5:0.05)        arc(85:77:1)    arc(160:343:0.05);

    \draw(0,0)  +(71:1) arc(71:65:1)    arc(155:90:0.085)   --(0.5,1.3);
    \draw(0,0) +(106:1) arc(106:115:1)  arc(25:90:0.085)    --(-0.5,1.3);
\end{tikzpicture}

Some text here below the picture
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\clip` is more cleaner than this.